# VBA Visible Cell Paste Error 1004

Tags: vba, excel

I have a VBA code that is getting a 1004 error when pasting visible cells:

> PasteSpecial method of Range class failed

I can comment out the paste and it will copy the visible cells so I can manually paste them, but the automated paste causes the error. I have confirmed that the sheet names are correct and have tried various types of paste special and just `.Paste`.

This is my code:

```
'Copies Column A visible rows
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("$A$2:$A$" & lastRow).SpecialCells  (xlCellTypeVisible).Copy

'Empties sheet
Sheets("Sheet2").Cells.ClearContents

'Pastes to sheet2
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: This error could be happening if the workbook hasn't been saved. Try saving and then pasting the values. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17281872/error-pastespecial-method-of-range-class-failed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the `ClearContents` prior to the `Copy` - the `ClearContents` method is an operation that empties the clipboard.

```
'Empties sheet
Sheets("Sheet2").Cells.ClearContents

'Copies Column A visible rows
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("$A$2:$A$" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy

'Pastes to sheet2
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13988783/range-clearcontents-clears-the-system-clipboard-workaround-vba-excel

Comment: You are my hero. This fixed it.